# Loading Qt plugin dynamically with Qt 5.10

Tags: visual-studio, qt

Recently, we ported our tool from Qt 4.8.x to Qt 5.10. We make use of the Qt plugins for developing our application. We were able to successfully port the pluin and application to Qt 5.10. But however there is a runtime error when loading the plugin. We make use of QPluginLoader to dynamically load the plugin. Also, it was decided that we place the required Qt DLLs locally in our application runtime directory instead of installing the whole Qt runtime library. We found using dependency walker that the following Qt DLLs are used

- Qt5Core.DLL
- Qt5Gui.DLL
- Qt5Network.DLL
- Qt5Sql.DLL
- Qt5Widgets.DLL

Now when loading the plugin, we get the error as seen in the image, after which the QPluginLoader's error string contains the error "Failed to extract plugin metadata from xyz.dll"[image]

From the face of it, looks like some project configuration problem. But, I can't seem to understand what. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Qt 5 uses the plugin system itself for the various platform specific DLLs, so you won't see the required DLLs by a static analysis through dependency walker. Try profiling the application to see additional dynamic dependencies (Dependency Walker -> Profile -> Start Profiling). Things like qwindows.dll will probably show up. Or use Qt's windeploy tool to get a decent deployment structure

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll check.

Comment: Seems that you must use [macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_PLUGIN_METADATA) to define plugin's metadata.

Take a look at this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications) for more info